# Jenkins - Batch wait till process is up and kill if it hangs

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I’m using Jenkins on Windows and want to run csscript that launch an application and execute automatic tests, now I want to create a time out so in case the application is running more than about 30 minutes it will be killed,

I have this batch script: first I create a FOR loop that wait till the application is up and then another FOR loop that check if the application is up more than 25 minutes.

The problem is I’m getting this error in the first loop
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
I read the info on wiki but didn’t really understand how to solve my issue
Please help

```
start cscript //nologo D:\tets.vbs
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,20) DO (
    echo Round number %%A

    REM find the running executable
    tasklist | find /I /C "App.exe" > nul
    echo ERRORLEVEL is !ERRORLEVEL!
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 EXIT

    rem wait 3 seconds
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul
)
FOR /L %%U IN (1,1,50) DO (
    echo Round number %%U

    REM find the running executable
    tasklist | find /I /C "App.exe" > nul
    echo ERRORLEVEL is !ERRORLEVEL!
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 EXIT

    rem wait 30 seconds
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 > nul
)
echo TASKILL
taskkill /f /im App.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to timeout a build, use the **[Build-timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)**

**Edit:**
The suggestion for the article you linked is to use the `at` command. Instead of:
`start cscript //nologo D:\tets.vbs`
use
`at %time% start cscript //nologo D:\tets.vbs`
You will have to calculate the next `%time%` (in minutes), and obviously the job will have to wait for that minute to start, so at best a 1 second delay, at worse a 59 second delay.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but in case of timeout I want Jenkins run the next csscript and not abort entire build

Comment: hmmm, can you send an example how to implement this in a batch file ?

Comment: Something like `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=: " %%A IN (\`time /T\`) DO ( SET /A "time=%%A+1" )` but you have to account for 59th minute rolling over to next hour, etc. And 12th hour, rolling over to 1 or 13 depending on your localle, etc